# How do I jump to a specific place on a page?

Tags: uri

I wish to be able to jump to a specific place on a given page.

I have inserted `<a name="placetojumpto"></a>` into the text of the page, and set the link to the page to be "about_us/customers/#placetojumpto."

If I type the URL in the address bar it works fine, but when I try use the link generated by Drupal, it converts the "#" to "%2523," so the link becomes "about_us/customers/%2523placetojumpto" and then fails.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that you have the #, called fragment, in the path, Drupal escapes it for you, and what you need to do is tell Drupal specifically that you want a fragment in the url.

Example:

```
l('linktext', 'node/1', array('fragment' => 'placetojumpto'));
```

Documentation here: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/l/7

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the / before the #

So your link will be

`<a href="about_us/customers#placetojumpto">Link here</a>`

Then your link will go to the #placetojumpto anchor on the customers page :-)

Comment: While there is indeed a / to much, isn't the real problem that he embeds the fragment where it get's escaped?

Answer (score -1):

This works for me in drupal 7: `<a href="#contact" id="contact">Contact</a>`